# Command to use all CPUs for (an already) running command

Tags: command-line

I ran a command from terminal. I did not use any parallelization techniques.

The command is currently running on my system and completed quarter(25%) of the work. Took a whole day for that first quarter. Three quarters(75%) of work is remaining for completion.

Can I parallelize it now without disturbing the running command?

Answer (score 1):

To parallelize a process it needs to be done from the start and the process must support parallel processing.

A way to speed up the process is to elevate the CPU priority a process have with the `nice` command https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nice_(Unix) and the priority can be changed with `renice`.